# Column vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am very new to MATLAB and I was wondering if anyone can suggest how to construct a Nx1 column vector with all the entries being 0, except for the last entry which is 1.
I tried playing with the following commands with no luck

```
A=zeros(N,1)
B=ones(N,1)
C=horzcat(A,B)
Cvector=C(:)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cvector = zeros(N, 1);
Cvector(end) = 1;
```